# PHP File include error

Tags: php

I have the following code in a PHP page. Some times when I delete the cache2.html file, I expect the php to recreate it and the next person will get the cache2.html instead of executing the php code. I get the following warning some times on the page and no content. Is it because of multiple users accessing the php concurrently? If so, How do I fix it? Thank you.

> Warning: include(dir1/cache2.html) [function.include]: failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/content/54/site/index.php on line 8

```
<?php 
if (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip')) ob_start("ob_gzhandler"); else ob_start();

$cachefile = "dir1/cache2.html";
if (file_exists($cachefile)) {
        include($cachefile); // output the contents of the cache file
} else {

/* HTML (BUILT USING PHP/MYSQL) */

$cachefile = "dir1/cache2.html";
$fp = fopen($cachefile, 'w'); 
fwrite($fp, ob_get_contents()); 
fclose($fp);
ob_flush(); // Send the output to the browser
}  
?>
```

Comment: One way to fix it would be to not delete the file while someone is accessing the page.  This isn't a troll answer as much as it sounds like one, but trying to do what it sounds like you want to do would require much more complexity, and its important to know whether you need it.

Comment: Thats the cache I build to avoid Database calls for every request. I clear that every time there is a change to my site's content (which happens every hour or so). What other options I have to achieve this caching?

Comment: Your caching solution isn't bad, its just the error handling that could be improved.  I like AlexHowansky's second suggestion below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calls to file_exists() are themselves cached, so it's likely you're getting a return value of true even after the file is deleted. See:

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php

So, you could do:

```
clearstatcache();
if (file_exists($cache)) {
    include($cache);
} else {
    // generate page
}
```

Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
if (file_exists($cache) && @include($cache)) {
    exit;
} else {
    // generate page
}
```

Or better, if you're deleting the cache file from within a PHP process, then just call clearstatcache() after you delete the file.

Comment: I much prefer the second method as it would catch the (possibly edge-)case where the file was deleted between when it existed and when it was included.  In the second case, if include fails (even if it just moments before existed) the page is still generated.

Comment: That @ is something that I do not rally like. You might try instead a try/catch, that would be more elegant.

Comment: Failed includes don't throw exceptions.